# геопозиционирование

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, моб.приложение для такси компании будет ли сложным ? И расскажите пожалуйста, например клиент заказывает такси и после заказа у таксистов в приложении должен отображается заявка присланный клиентом, после принятия заказа, клиент может прямо на карте набюдать где его таксист. Как это реализовать ? не пинайте сильно. обьясните структуру. Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 0):

Обычная бд. MYSQL. Лучше используй Innodb под твои задачи она больше зайдет если приложение будет высоконагруженно. 
Принципа работы такой у бд. Есть таблицы: prefix_task, prefix_users, prefix_autos.

- prefix_task включает в себя столбцы user, auto, pay, a, b, status

  1. user это id заказчика в системе
  2. auto это id работника в системе
  3. pay это цена поездки высчитываемая по алгоритму в приложении (можно
     это все сделать синхронизировав апи яндекс карт или гугл мапс
  4. a и b это точки отправки и прибытия (тупо названия)
  5. status это состояние заказа взял ли его кто-то

> выборку заказов можно опять же сделать как обычную `SELECT * FROM
>   prefix_task WHERE status=0` ,так и по точкам использовать места вблизи
>   (также синхронизация с я картами или гугл).
>   Думаю не нужно писать что эт овсе нужно сделать в форме API не напрямую из приложения обращаться к бд.

- prefix_users любой человек что зашел в приложение, ему присваивается уникальный айди и все это дело происходит без регистрации (дружелюбный интерфейс, можно конечно и регистрацию и все это дело сделать на ваше усмотрение)
- prefix_autos это уже информация о водителях (тут думаю регистрация нужна и различные поля на ваш вкус и цвет как вы решите, только одно обязательное поле нас интересует для работы всей нашей системы это id, howtask, au)

  1.id это уникальный постоянный индентификатор водителя

  2.howtask сколько заказов он выполнил и из этого идет формула партнерской вычеты программы howtask - howtask*0.10 (к примеру)

  3.au Автомобиль нашего работника

> Вся реализация проходит отправкой обычных post Запросов на сервер api
>   из приложения. А дизайн и прочее можно взять готовые библиотеки из
>   android studio под каталоги и переделать их)

Comment: Если что innodb работает раз в 5 медленнее MyISAM, так что связывать нагруженность приложения и innodb как то не верно. Правда MyISAM не надежен при сбоях. И если нужен боле менее свой адекватный поиск ближайших к точке водителей (не перебором полного списка и прогоном его через api яндекс/google), лучше было бы все таки взять БД рассчитанную на работу с географией, например postgresql с раширением postgis, которое обеспечивает очень быстрый поиск по индексу "ближайших точек" и еще кучу всего